# How can I compile XCode 4.5 project from the command line

Tags: objective-c, gcc, terminal, llvm, xcode4.5

I've created simple *Command line* app from XCode 4.5, however I'd need to compile it from the command line. If I remove `@autoreleasepool` block and *literal array initialization* I can compile it with following command:

```
gcc main.m -o prog -ObjC -framework Foundation
```

Is it possible to compile it **with** autoreleasepool and literals?

*main.m* (for clarity I've removed irrelevant parts)

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSArray *array = @[@"foo", @"bar"];
        NSLog(@"%@", array);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
> gcc main.m -o prog -ObjC -framework Foundation
main.m: In function ‘main’:
main.m:6: error: stray ‘@’ in program
main.m:6: error: ‘autoreleasepool’ undeclared (first use in this function)
main.m:6: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
main.m:6: error: for each function it appears in.)
main.m:7: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
main.m:8: error: stray ‘@’ in program
```

Comment: I believe by default the compiler makes use of the ARC, hence when you put in `autoreleasepool` it fails. You need to insert the compiler flag to denote that you are compiling with ARC disabled. Let me know if this worked out for you and I will post a proper answer for other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clang is the preferred compiler for Objective-C. New features (autorelease scopes, ARC, literals, etc.) aren't added to gcc, and it'll be removed in a future Xcode release.

Usage of clang from the commandline is very similar to gcc, so this should work instead:

```
clang main.m -o prog -ObjC -framework Foundation
```

You'll need to have the Xcode command line tools (Xcode menu > Open Developer Tool > More Developer Tools) installed.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind getting `xcodebuild` to build it for you (rather than invoking the compiler yourself), you can do this:

```
xcrun xcodebuild -project path/to/project.xcodeproj -target NameOfTarget -configuration Release
```

To send the build products to a location that you specify, you can add `'CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=path/to/build_output_directory'` to the command line arguments.

See the `xcodebuild` help for alternative ways to invoke it.